# Get information of user editing excel document

Tags: office-js

I am making an Excel Add-in with office-js. I am trying to replicate functionality from Google Sheets which was served by `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("user_name");`

Is it possible to get the name of the user currently editing the document as it appears in File > Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [Excel.DocumentProperties.lastAuthor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.documentproperties?view=office-js#lastauthor) work for your scenario?

If not, there is a preview API that enables you to get a JSON token that includes the ID of the user currently logged into Office. See [Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=office-js) for the reference doc. But see also [SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean using VBA, but if you do, you can do this:

```
Function GetUserID()
    GetUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
    End Function
```

Comment: I am using office-js. Thanks though.